# Make Pointer Icon in expandable list Bold

Tags: android, xml, colors, expandablelistview

I have created an expandable list and have put the pointer icon as an arrow. Is there a way to make this icon bold to make it stand out?

**The Arrow Here is unclear and i want to make it darker**

[image: Arrow Expandable list]

**XML For Expandable List View**

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandable_list_view3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:pointerIcon="arrow"></ExpandableListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the pointer image as you want and then call it to the `ExpandableView`. An example of this:

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_list_view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/arrow" />
```

Now define the `arrow.xml`.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/up_arrow" 
     android:state_expanded="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/down_arrow" 
     android:state_expanded="true" />
</selector>
```

You have to define two images for expanded state and contracted state. 
You could also look into [Reference Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PointerIcon.html) you are persistent to use `PointerIcon`. The Doc says:

> Pointer icons can be provided either by the system using system types, or by applications using bitmaps or application resources.

Comment: Was your question answered?